# How to pass an array in the Uri to a WCF WEB API service?

Tags: wcf, wcf-web-api

Is there a way to pass an array of values to WCF WEB API service using a GET? I want to make the following call to my service:

```
http://localhost/myservice.com/projects/workspaceUsers?token=A3AD62998A7A463A9AD23D8F2937C92220120325072846&workspaceId=208&workspaceId=209
```

My web service function looks like:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "workspaceUsers?token={token}&workspaceId={workspaceId}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage<IEnumerable<WorkspaceUserReadOnlyChildData>> FetchWorkspaceUserList(string token, int workspaceId)
```

The thought was to just change int workspaceId to int[] workspaceId, but that leads to the following error:

```
The service operation 'FetchWorkspaceUserList' will never receive a value for the input parameter 'workspaceId' of type 'Int32[]'. Ensure that a request HttpOperationHandler has an output parameter with a type assignable to 'Int32[]'.
```

Is there any way to do this without doing something like passing a criteria object using a POST?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you try comma seperated values, instead of int array. Had you been using ASP.Net MVC or the new Web API, you could have used ModelBinders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do is just update to ASP.NET 4 WEB API. Since it operates off of the standard controller architecture, you can easily pass in arrays.

Comment: I discovered that was the best solution as well.